# You always are online or you are always online?

Tags: adverbs

Which one is correct and why?
Please answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The adverb "always" most commonly is placed between the subject and main verb. Refer to the following link for concise explanation and examples.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/always

Personally, when speaking this sentence out loud, the latter choice sounds better, but both are grammatically correct.